# Add title to center of zoomable sunburst circle (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with the [**Zoomable Sunburst**](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst) on D3 Observable. I want to show the clicked label in the center circle.

So instead of this:

[image]

I need to see something like this:

[image]

But as you can see the **label isn't remaining centered**. I am currently using the following to add the label in the center circle on click, as you see in the previous GIF:

```
d3.select("#title").remove()
const main_title = g.append("text").attr("id", "title")
.attr("dx", function(d) {
    return -20
})
.style("font-size", "18px").attr("text-anchor", "center")
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    p.x = 9,
    p.y = 10;
return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
})
.text(p.data.name);
```

This is placed inside the **clicked(p)** function.

How can I **ensure the label is centered regardless of text length**. Also, ensure the label appears when the visual first loads, so you don't have to click on it to see the first one.

Comment: Where is your fork?

Comment: I am working with the downloaded code, not the fork.

Comment: In that case, fork that one and add your code for creating the labels, so we just need to center it.

Comment: Another thing: there is no `center` for text-anchor, it should be `middle`.